# How to format jquery functions?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this current function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".test").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'  });
});
```

And i want to be able to add this line to it:

```
onSelect: var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate')
```

How would i format this correctly, can someone show me an example of it. I am new to using jquery, so i dont really know much about it.

Comment: That line doesn't make sense.

Comment: The one you refer to as "this line".

Comment: Oh sorry, i just want to be able to add the onselect method to the function, but i do not know how to format it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onSelect` is one of the options you can set on the datepicker, so you just have to add it to after the `dateFormat` option you already had.

`onSelect` is meant to be a function, so you have to wrap the code you wanted to run inside a function declaration. Additionally, jQuery will automatically pass the selected date and the instance of the datepicker into that function when it's called, hence the parameters shown below:

```
$(function() {
    $(".test").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',  
        onSelect: function(selectedDate, instance) {
            var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery has extensive [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). You should always look there first; chances are they can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah thankyou! How would i go about doing it so that in the alert, it does not come up with the time and the timezone also?

Comment: Try alerting the `selectedDate` parameter in the function -- it should contain the date you selected (in `dd/mm/yy` format). You probably don't need the `var dateObject...` line at all.

Comment: Ah ok ty, I have another problem though, I have two textboxes which will both contain the data. How do i do it so that you click the first one, and that value goes into one var. Then you click the next one, it then goes into the secondary var?

Comment: @CallumHolden: I would stick to one question per thread. You should ask a new question with relevant HTML markup and JS code. If I answered your original question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok I will ask a new question, and I will once my timer runs out +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());
```

Then use this date in the datepicker.